# FileStorage --> mysql

Tags: c++, mysql

sorry for my english :) Trying to improve my application I want to copy vectors directly into mysql without string, is it even possible?

```
FileStorage fs( ".yml", FileStorage::WRITE + FileStorage::MEMORY );

Ptr < FaceRecognizer > model0 = createmyfisherRecognizer();

model0->train( images, labels );

model0->save( fs );




void myfisher::save( FileStorage & fs ) const {

    static char * host = "localhost"; /* host serwera MySQL */
    static char * user = "root"; /* nazwa loginu by polaczyc sie do serwera */
    static char * password = ""; /* haslo */
    static char * sql_db = "fisher"; /* nazwa bazy */
    static unsigned int sql_port = NULL; /* port na jakim odbiera/wysyla serwer mysql */
    static char * opt_socket = NULL; /* socket name */
    static unsigned int sql_flags = 0;
    static MYSQL * sock; /* Wskaznik do polaczenia do MySQL */

    sock = mysql_init( NULL );

    if( mysql_real_connect( sock, host, user, password, sql_db, sql_port, opt_socket, sql_flags ) )
         cout << "Poprawnie polaczyles sie z baza danych" << endl;
    else
         cout << "Blad w polaczeniu z baza danych" << endl;

    fs << "num_components" << _num_components;
    fs << "mean" << _mean;
    fs << "eigenvalues" << _eigenvalues;
    writeFileNodeList( fs, "projections", _projections );
    fs << "labels" << _labels;

    string buf = fs.releaseAndGetString();

    fs.release();

    string zapytanie = "insert into baa values (\"" + buf + "\")";

    if( !mysql_query( sock, zapytanie.c_str() ) )
         cout << "Poprawnie dodano" << endl;
    else
         cout << "Blad przy zapisywaniu" << endl;

}
```

Here I posted the code in question. At the moment it works in this way:

1. everything is saved into fs (FileStorage)
2. data in fs is converted to string
3. fs sent to database
   It is known that the program would run much faster if it would be directly copied without the string to the database.

Comment: "It is known that the program would run faster without string" O really? The string is just an in-memory operation, the database write is I/O. I wouldn't be so sure. The face recognizer isn't going to be fast, either.

Answer (score 0):

i think you can use [snprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/snprintf/) for this, unfortunatelly since there are variable types missing i cant give you exact example.

```
char string[100];
snprintf(string, 100, "printe text %s,\n and integer %i", "printf", 100); //almost same as printf
```